# Does try except function catch a return 0 happening inside a method on which we are running try except on?

Tags: python, try-catch, return-value

If I put a try: except block on this if statement, will the return 0 condition be reported as an exception?

(The if statements below are inside a method)

```
if x:
   do something
elif y:
   do something 
else:
   print("Please use valid condition")
   return 0
```

Comment: The short answer is: no. Did you find that it did something different?

Comment: No, a return is not an exception. `try` will catch exceptions that have been `raise`d; either directly by you or a function that you call inside the `try`.

Comment: So what should I use if I fall inside the else condition? Should I do a sys.exit()?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do. If you want to exit the program completely, then `exit` may be appropriate. You haven't given much background in the question though.

Comment: `raise ValueError("Unexpected value for x and y")` would seem like a reasonable replacement for `return 0`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I am developing an algorithm which uses many classes and I want to exit my program if I fall in certain conditions that are invalid. So sys.exit() is the only way to do that? I thought there was a tidier way. 
I didn't want to waste everyone's time with a lot of details, tried to make the question as simple as I could. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @TomDalton cool! So the try except method would catch this?? I am actually new to python and not that much of a programmer.

Comment: "So the try except method would catch this?" Yes, you'd catch the ValueError exception.